# python argparse -h like behaviour and mutually exclusive arguments

Tags: python, argparse, required

My script will normally accept a required argument like so `script.py PATH` but I also what to be able to call it like so `script.py -e EXPRESSION` and omit `PATH` alltogether.

Is there a way to do that with argparse?

For backwards compatibility I want to add this feature but not change the existing behaviour for example by having paths be passed with `script.py --path PATH` instead of just `script.py PATH`

I expect that this shouldn't be too hard as it is similar to the behaviour of -h.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a mutual exclusion group including an optional positional argument

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(usage='%(prog)s [-h] (PATH | -e EXPRESSION)')
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
group.add_argument("PATH", nargs='?', help="Path")
group.add_argument("-e", "--expression", help="Regular expression")

print parser.parse_args()
```

The default usage doesn't show the exclusivity group as well as between two regular arguments, that's why I have added a custom usage.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the option "default" so that, even if you do not specify the parameter, it will be assigned anyways:
Example:

```
parser.add_argument("-p", "--path", action=selected_path, default=".",
                help="Specify the path for execution.")
parser.add_argument("-e", "--expression", action=expression_value, default=0,
                help="Specify the expression for execution.")
```

Comment: The problem is that i want to combine in a mutually exclusive way positional and a non positional argument.